# Unsure how to decode output from pyserial read command

Tags: python, byte, decode, pyserial

In response to a query for data, when I read byte-by-byte with the pyserial read command, I get output I can't quite figure out what to do with.  Some of the bytes make sense, but quite a few of the bytes are this:  `b'\xac'`

When I try to decode with utf-8, I get the error:  `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 0: invalid start byte`.

The list command converts to a number (172), but that doesn't quite make sense either based on the numbers I expect from the device I'm querying.

my code for extracting the bytes:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('Com4')
ser.baudrate=38400
readbyte=[]
byteindex=0
read byte.append(ser.read())
print(readbyte[byteindex])
while readbyte[byteindex] is not None:
    byteindex=byteindex+1
    readbyte.append(ser.read())
    print(readbyte[byteindex])
```

and what I get as a result are lines like this:

```
b'A'
b'\xb1'
b'B'
b'A'
b'\xac'
b'A'
b'\xac'
b'S'
b'D'
b'\xd8'
b'\xac'
```

and so on.  It seems like the '\x' might be some sort of delimiter?  I've tried looking around online but haven't found anything of any help.

Comment: What kind of output format do you expect from the device? Know that may help decode the bytes you're getting.

Comment: The manual for the equipment I'm connected to is a bit vague, but based on that I was expecting a comma delimited string.  With some characters (A, B, S, D, etc) and some numbers.  So the returned lines that are letters make sense.  The others, not so much.

Comment: The `\xac` values are the hexadecimal representation of bytes of the string that aren't regular characters. As you note this is 172 in decimal. If you subtract 128 from it, you get 44, which is the ASCII code for a `,` comma character. So it looks like its high-bit is being set. Doing the same thing to the `\xd8` results in 44, which is ASCII for the character `X`. Do you have a link to the device's manual so I could take a look at it?

Comment: Ah, that makes a big of sense, though still a bit unclear to me how I decode.  The manual is here:  https://wmo-gaw-wcc-aerosol-physics.org/files/aps_3321.pdf.  Page C21 indicates the Read Record command and page C26 indicates the format of RRA - or record A output (the other records have similar issues)

Comment: Hmm, the manual certainly is unclear — and the output you're getting seems inconsistent. Obviously you need to subtract 128 to remove the high-bit, but it doesn't look like it's being set on every byte received and I'm not sure if there's a pattern to when it's done or not. While it might be possible to figure that out, I would first try to get support the manufacturer.

Comment: P.S. Make sure you're using the proper serial port configuration for the device (i.e. parity, number of start and stop bits, etc) because that not be right might be affecting the data being retrieved — right now it looks like your code is just using whatever the `pyserial` defaults are.

Comment: Ah - that seemed to make a difference - setting parity, bytesize, stopbit now seems to give a lot more what I would expect - still getting blanks between most commas which is a bit weird, but I think I'm on the right path - thanks SO MUCH for your help!!